# valgrind vgdb with gdb in emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, gdb, valgrind

I'm trying to use valgrind vgdb with command: `valgrind --vgdb-error=0 ./a.out [args]`.

when I run `target remote | /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb` in emacs gdb I get `Non-stop mode requested, but remote does not support non-stop` error.

The gdb command runed by emacs is: `gdb -i=mi a.out`.

my versions of valgrind, gdb and emacs:
valgrind-3.7.0, GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.5.1-2.5.1) and GNU Emacs 24.2.1.

Is there a way to resolve the problem or my versions of gdb, valgrind or emacs can't handle what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently valgrind gdbserver does not support non stop mode and it is
difficult to implement it (see https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=328081 )

So, when using the gdb mode of emacs, the non stop mode has to be disabled.
  M-x customize-option
  gdb-non-stop-setting
set it off + Apply and Save

After that, emacs + vgdb + valgrind should work properly together.